# Css auto height with font-size

Tags: css, height

I have a link and underneath a span element

```
<a href="#" style="display:inline-block;font-size:900%">12</a>
<span display="block">ACTIVE</span>
```

The problem is that if I don't give precise height to the 'a' element the height is not changing and they  overlap. 
I want on my responsive rule to change only the size of the fonts is that possible ?

Comment: I take it your actual code has proper style tags attached? anchor is missing `display` and span tag you seem to have used a display attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline-block` is an incorrect property on its own. It should be `display:inline-block;`

Have you tried adding a matching `line-height: 100%;` property?

Answer (score 0):

`a,span{height: npx}` Just apply the height to both the a and the span in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your question completely. But I think you should try to use min-height or max-height instead of height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of percent and em in a and normal in span.

```
a {font-size:9em;}
span {font-size:normal;}
```